# Correct use of apply-functions for producing a list from list element combinations

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a list object that looks like this

```
list1 <- list(c("A1", "A2"), "B", c("C1", "C2"))
```

From this I want to produce a list that includes lists of a all element combinations in list1. For list1 it should look like this

```
list2 <- list(list("A1", "B", "C1"), list("A1", "B", "C2"), list("A2", "B", "C1"), list("A2", "B", "C2"))
```

With even more elements in list1, this becomes impossible to produce manually. How do I go about doing this in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest something a little bit different. Just use `expand.grid` and get a `data.frame` of the combinations:

```
expand.grid(list1)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1   A1    B   C1
# 2   A2    B   C1
# 3   A1    B   C2
# 4   A2    B   C2
```

Or, similarly, with "data.table", use `CJ`:

```
library(data.table)
do.call(CJ, list1)
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1: A1  B C1
# 2: A1  B C2
# 3: A2  B C1
# 4: A2  B C2
```